# Staged labels for xaxis with zero values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to draw a [combination chart](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types) with two series represented with bars. Each one has its own xaxis, on the top and in the bottom. In my example I have one of them with zero values. The problem is that xaxis for the series with zero values is staged (bottom xaxis in the example). I don't know why. If I modify the series to non-zero values the xaxis labels are perfect.

```
  $(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    "colors": ["#00bdbd","#666666"],
    "legend": {
      "align": "center",
      "verticalAlign": "top",
      "x": 0,
      "y": 10,
      "borderWidth": 0
    },
    "xAxis": {
      "labels": {
        "rotation": 0,
        "align": "right",
        "staggerLines": 1,
        "y": 4
      },
      "title": {
        "style": {
          "color": "#757477"
        }
      },
      "categories": ["Asturias","Cantabria"],
      "lineWidth": 0,
      "tickLength": 0
    },
    "yAxis": [{
      "title": {
        "text": "Tourists",
        "style": {
          "color": "#666666"
        }
      },
      "min": 0
    },
    {
      "title": {
        "text": "Tourists",
        "style": {
          "color": "#666666"
        }
      },
      "min": 0,
      "opposite": true
    }],
    "series": [{
      "name": "Zero",
      "type": "bar",
      "data": [0,0],
      "yAxis": 0,
      "stack": 0,
      "zIndex": 0,
      "animation": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Visits",
      "type": "bar",
      "data": [8000,3000],
      "yAxis": 1,
      "stack": 1,
      "zIndex": 0,
      "animation": true
    }]
  });
});
```

In this [highcharts example](http://jsfiddle.net/deibiz/2wusojab/) you can see the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [staggerLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.staggerLines) parameter as 1.

```
labels:{
     staggerLines:1
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wusojab/1/

Comment: Thank you, I supposed that the default behaviour was staggerLines:1